# MSBuild web package without additional files/directory structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild

Trying to use MSBuild 15.7 to create a web package of an ASP.NET MVC website for deployment, but just outputting to a local folder for now. It builds fine but creates a lot of files that I don't need as well as an unnecessary folder structure mimicking the path to the original solution file including: `[OUTPUT DIR]\Archive\Content\C_C\[PATH TO SOLUTION]\[SOLUTION NAME]\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\`. The same happens if I use the PackageAsSingleFile switch set to true and false (true just zips this folder hierarchy up).

Basically, I only want the contents of PackageTmp to be included in the web publish packageg (as these are the actual web site files I need to deploy).

Comment: Using `msbuild [PATH TO SOLUTION] /p:OutDir=[OUTPUT DIR]` kiiiiind of works, but now it creates a _PublishedWebsites directory in OUTPUT DIR as well as all of the compiled DLLs. Inside _PublishedWebsites I have the actual deployable website files. How do I suppress creation of all the other DLLs in the OUTPUT DIR root?

Comment: I'm deleting the files for now but there must be a better way...